# How get array in Angular template?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

**In PHP side** there are some element of array:

```
$this->data['messages']['ms'][] = 'Line1';
$this->data['messages']['ms'][] = 'Line2';
```

and method that to return json format:

```
echo json_encode($this->data['messages']); die();
```

**Angular side:**

```
$scope.response = {};
....
request.success(function (data) {
     $scope.response.message = data.messages; // Edit here
});


<div ng-repeat="error in response">{{error}}</div>
```

When I try to get array items, I get nothing

---

I have converted my difficult object to array:

```
$scope.messages = [];
...
// In loop
$scope.messages.push(item);
```

**Output in console:**
    Array[2]0: "Qeydiyyat mümkün deyil. Bu e-mail ilə istifadəçi artıq saytda qeydiyyatdan keçib"1: "Bu IP ünvanından artıq qeydiyyatdan keçilib"

In HTML template I try to display elements:

```
<div ng-repat="error in messages">{{error}}</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the AJAX request gets sent?

Comment: check your console, make sure there is any response data

Comment: data.message or data.messages?

Comment: Expanded my question

Answer (score 0):

you must check your request. Are you useing $http?
Have you provided http in controller/service?

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

you may also check with console.log(data) if theres any data provided.
Maybe there's different construction than you thought (for example wrapped data)

P.S. it should be messages (with s in the end)

Comment: I use `$http(POST)`, sure my response is:                                                       `Object {ms: Array[1], type: "error"}ms: Array[1]0: "Qeydiyyat mümkün deyil. Bu e-mail ilə istifadəçi artıq saytda qeydiyyatdan keçib"length: 1__proto__: Array[0]type: "error"__proto__: Object`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your angular side.

```
$scope.response = {};
....
 request.success(function (data) {
 $scope.message = data.data;
 console.log($scope.message);
 });

 <div ng-repeat="error in message">{{error}}</div>
```

You call your variable in a wrong way. Try console log the $scope.message if there are data's provided.

Comment: Does not work,look please at previous comment, I have given an response. Here is object with `ms`, `type`. At `ms` is array

Comment: This line `$scope.response.messages = data.messages;` gets `element(array)` of object `data`. `data.messages` looks like as at console: `0: "Qeydiyyat mümkün deyil. Bu e-mail ilə istifadəçi artıq saytda qeydiyyatdan keçib"`